# Multiple of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

In one of my classes we showed that  the sequence of Cesàro sums for a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent directly. My professor mentioned you could also show convergence by the Cauchy criterion, so now I want to prove that the Cesàro sum sequence is Cauchy myself. My proof thus far looks like this:

We want to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\bigg| \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n} - \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m} \bigg| < \epsilon $$
for all $n > m \geq N$, where $n > m$ by assumption. Since $(a_n)$ converges, $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, in particular $\forall\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$ for $n > m \geq N$. Now, we can rearrange the left-hand side of the inequality we want to show like so:
$$\bigg| \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n} - \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_m}{m} \bigg|$$
$$\bigg| \frac{m}{mn}(a_1+\ldots+a_n) - \frac{n}{mn}(a_1+\ldots+a_m) \bigg|$$
$$\bigg| \frac{(m-n)}{mn}(a_{m+1}+\ldots+a_n) \bigg|$$
$$\bigg| \frac{(m-n)}{mn} \bigg| \bigg| (a_{m+1}+\ldots+a_n) \bigg|$$
$$\bigg| \frac{(m-n)}{mn} \bigg| \bigg| a_n - a_m \bigg|$$
So the inequality in what we want to show is just a multiple of the inequality for the sequence we know is Cauchy. Here's where I get stuck. I can verify that a constant times a Cauchy sequence is still Cauchy, but does that apply here? Is the fraction in the end step even a constant if it varies with every $m,n$? I don't think so. Where can I go from here? Is this even the right direction?

Comment: Since $|a_n -a_m| < \varepsilon$ for all $n>m$ you can let $n\rightarrow \infty$ (and since $\{a_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ converges, say to $a^*$ there are no problems with this).  Your fraction will reduce to $|1/m|$ and you can then let $m\rightarrow \infty$ to see that you can make the right-hand side as small as you like, so it must be Cauchy

Comment: @postmortes Could what you said about the convergence of $(a_n)$ be used to show that the Cesaro sums converge to the same value as $(a_n)$?

Comment: Your simplifications are not correct after the second line.

Comment: I don't think so but I'm far from an expert on Cesaro summation.